# Setting percentage heights to flex items when container has dynamic height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple wrapper with 2 div elements in it.

I want the first one to gain 85% of the height and the second one to gain only 15% of the height.

It works when I set a fixed height to the wrapper. Though sadly my wrapper has a dynamic height.

Do you know how I can accomplish this?

I have also provided a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HQpahfmRasij8Zougjkn?p=preview

**Code:**

```css
.outer{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 0;
  /* if i set the fixed height everthing works
     though i do want a dynamic height
  height: 800px; */
}
.main {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 85%;
  max-height: 85%;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 400px;
}
.navigator {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  max-height: 15%;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="main" >
    <!-- this container should have 85% of the outer containers height -->
  </div>
  <div class="navigator" >
    <!-- this container should have 15% of the outer containers height -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There has to be a method of determining the height of the parent up the chain..if you can't do that it won't work. Where is your wrapper gettig it's height from etc?

Comment: its all a dynamic height. all done with flexbox css. i am using angular material design. so i guess ill have to write an eventlistener on rendering so that i can specifiy the height of the element?

Comment: Thing is it *will* work provided the wrapper height (flex:1) can be determined by the flexbox...if your chain *up* isn't complete...it breaks.

Comment: waiting for a context that would show how heights are being determinated, i come up with an example  within flex imbrication where height should be usable or something alike  with the flex properties : flex:85; & flex:15; http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pgOjXB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the initial (outer) layout without `flex`, as I can't see the point when it's not needed.

The requirement is the same though, that the `.outer`'s parent need a height, either inherited or set.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.outer {
  height: 100%;
}
.main {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
  display: flex;            /* this is for main's children */
  flex-direction: row;      /* this is for main's children */
}
.navigator {
  background-color: red;
  height: 15%;
  display: flex;            /* this is for nav's children */
  flex-direction: row;      /* this is for nav's children */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="main" >
    <!-- this container should have 85% of the outer containers height -->
  </div>
  <div class="navigator" >
    <!-- this container should have 15% of the outer containers height -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try sizing the flex items with `flex-grow` instead of `flex-basis` or `height`.

In the following example, one flex item will occupy 85% of the available space in the container. The other flex item will take the remaining 15%.

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {  flex-grow: 85; }
.navigator { flex-grow: 15; }  /* flex-grow: 1 would work as well */
```

[**Revised Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sm5pmjwvXad0wxHlEANE?p=preview)

Learn more about flex heights here: [Heights rendering differently in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

if they are direct childs of body, then you first need to set `height` on patrents : `html` & `body` in order to have an inheritable value.

then `outer` is no longer needed, `body` is there already.

Set `height` to the smallest (and eventually a min-height) and request the other to grow via just : `flex:1;`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
  background: tomato;
}
.navigator {
  height: 15%;
  min-height: 2em;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <!-- this container should have 85% of the outer containers height -->
  main
</div>
<div class="navigator">
  navigator
  <!-- this container should have 15% of the outer containers height -->
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/R502OvyV2RR8GZ96UJvt?p=preview

comment pulled up here :

> @JuHwon then, does the parent has a known size that it can be
>   inherited.
>   could you set up an example that shows your trouble. 
>   **% values need a reference** to calculate a ratio from it, within flex imbrication **height should be usable or something like
>   `flex:85;` & `flex:15;`** http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pgOjXB

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. sadly they are not children of body. these are elements (tiles) deep in the html structure.. i can not get this work with a wrapper.

Comment: @JuHwon then, does the parent has a known size that it can be inherited. could you set up an example that shows your trouble. % values need a reference to calaculate a ratio from it, within flex imbrication height should be usable or something like flex:85; & flex:15; http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pgOjXB