# Chrome not accepting Flex or height % CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Hi I got an issue with my page where I have used Flex and height:x% to achieve a very botched but working responsive height for two divs within a container.

The problem I have is that it works fine in FF but not Chrome. (Assume IE, edge etc) doesn't either.

Here is what it looks like in FF: http://prntscr.com/a712g6 (this is what it should be)

Here it is in Chrome: http://prntscr.com/a712q4

Below is the code: (excuse the mess its a hacked up copy and paste of source code)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css?v=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/content.css?v=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/footer.css?v=1.0">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>      
        <div class="container">
            <div class="MainHeader">

            </div>
            <div class="logged_container">
                You are Logged in as <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Ryan</span> (<a href='logoff.php'>Log Out</a>)
            </div>
            <div class="navigation_container">          
                <a href="main.php">
                    <img src="img/test.png" alt="" height="16" style="vertical-align:top; padding-right:5px;">Home              
                </a>
            </div>


    <div class='content'>
        <div class='contentTableView' style="flex: 1; flex-direction: column;  min-height:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
            <span class="contentHeader">Title</span>
            <div id="map" class="map" style="float:left; width: 40%; margin-top: 1%; height:90%; min-height:90%; margin-left:20px; border:1px solid #0a639d;"></div>

            <div id="controls" class="controls" style="float:left; width: 40%; margin-top: 1%; height:90%; min-height:90%; margin-left:10%; border:1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); background-image: url('img/bms47.png');"></div>

        </div>
    </div>      


        <div class="footer">
            Footer Text
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

**EDIT: ATTACHED CSS**
http://pastebin.com/59rcgQwM

**EDIT2: Issue Example** 
[jsfiddle.net/vctbszc2/3](http://jsfiddle.net/vctbszc2/3) – Adam Buchanan Smith

Comment: done. see the edit above.

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276

Comment: is your issue here? https://jsfiddle.net/vctbszc2/3/

Comment: Hi Adam yes this is the issue.

Comment: Hi Adam have you got any ideas?