# Why does flexbox only cap child height in chrome?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, flexbox

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        child1
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        <div class="child3" style="height: 100px;">
            child3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child1 {
  height: 40px;
  flex: none;
}
.child2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

**child3** represents a self contained element that has a variable height.

As its height increase, I want it to stretch **child2** height, but not go past **parent**'s height, which is the parent flex container.

I have set a known height to **parent** here to simplify the problem, but it self depends on the rest of the page layout.

Why does it works on chrome but not IE or firefox?

illustration of the problem once **child3** has grown past **parent**'s height:
[image]

Illustration of the correct behaviour I see in chrome dev tools:
[image]

Here is the fiddle with colors to help see the problem (click the button a few times): https://jsfiddle.net/xa4tu4sr/8/

I need **child3** computed height to be capped, meaning it should scroll or just have its overflow hidden.

I do not recognize this as a bug in https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Maybe it's just a flesh wound!

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe in IE11-10

Comment: possibly related: [Heights rendering differently in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padding` in the parent to "correct" that, or set a background color for the parent. That works for me.

Based on what you added to your post, you will need to check the size of your DIV before increasing it, for this you can do something similar to this on your java file:

```
var counter = 10;
var div = document.querySelector('.child3');

window.increaseHeight = function (){
  if (counter<15) div.style.height = ++counter * 10 + "px";
}
```

You can compare the actual size of the DIV instead, or any other way you find adequate to solve your issue, but the bottom line is that you will need to check the size of your DIV before changing it's size, and that will prevent compatibility issues.

Comment: maybe a fiddle and explanation would help the OP understand where come the mistake (height or box grown from its content ? ) https://jsfiddle.net/xa4tu4sr/10/ beside does he want clipping or overflow ?

Comment: Thanks for adding that, this helps a bit more. ;)

Comment: Sadly I am making a self contained element (represented here as child3) that could be used in any context. This flexbox context is one of them. So child3 should really just try to extend its height on its own, being constrained by flexbox. It cannot know about its parents.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

Here is the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xa4tu4sr/11/

```
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child2 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

overflow: hidden; needs to be present on all the parent chain.

Contrary to what I thought, the result then is **not** that child3 overflow will be hidden, it's own height is now **capped** so it does cannot overflow.

It means that the internal layout of child 3 is now correct, since its computed height does not go beyond visible space. Otherwise, a div that would be defined to be at the bottom of child3 would be clipped for example.