# Flex container with overflow-y element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have flex .wrapper with flex-direction: column.

Then I have 2 flex elements. One of them is .g-main, which also is flex container with element .content inside it.

The troubles with height of .g-main. Why it doesn't stretches automamicly? There is a lot of content inside it.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276

Comment: if you set an height in the flex parent or to itself without reset in mediaquerie, it won't stretch, could you setup a snippet or a jsfiddle/codepen, that mimic your issue ?

Comment: Ssory, I forgot about jsfiddle. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/bvv73c9e/
Try to resize the content area on jsfiddle for @media working.

Comment: Maybe i'm sleepy, but looks like I was fixed it. :)

Comment: Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/bvv73c9e/3/. I don't really understand what I've done, seriously. Maybe added another height: 100p;