# flex div won't grow to parent height in Chrome

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser, flexbox

I've been messing around with flex in CSS lately. My goal was to create a layout with several columns with equal height and that the contents are equally spaced in between. I found a solution that works in Firefox but not in Chrome (minimal example with erroneous behaviour):

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS (gets autoprefixed):

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  .col-sm-6 > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;

    .item {
      height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 2px;
    }
  }
}
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zn463f1j/

Here are images of how the two browsers render the same fiddle:

Firefox (how it should be):
[image: Firefox]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

So my question is what styles do I need to add, remov or change in order to get it working in both browsers.

I tried athe following CSS but that resulted in firefox also rendering it like Chrome. Changing `height` from `100%` to `auto` made the code work in Firefox again but still not in Chrome.

```
.row .col-sm-6 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: related: [Heights Rendering Differently in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer. Check the code and result below.

Result:

[image]

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row .col-sm-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row .col-sm-6 > div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row .col-sm-6 > div .item {
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```