# Why does my layout="column" flex="50" not get honoured?

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

Using angular material I'm trying to have a basic layout with a column containing two divs each taking 50% of the height.

When the divs are empty this is working fine but when they have unequal content the 50% flex is ignored and the div with more content takes up more of the height.

I have a [codepen](http://codepen.io/craigsh/pen/ZWdZdq) demonstrating the problem.

Here's my code:

```
<div ng-cloak ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <div layout="row" class="outer-row">
      <div flex="50" layout="column">
        <h3>Both divs are 50% height</h3>
        <div flex="50" class="inner-column">
        </div>
        <div flex="50" class="inner-column">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div flex="50" layout="column">
        <h3>Both divs are 50% height but 2nd grows because it has more content</h3>
        <div flex="50" class="inner-column" layout="column">
          <p>A little content</p>
          <p>A little content</p>
          <p>A little content</p>
        </div>
        <div flex="50" class="inner-column" layout="column">
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
          <p>A lot of content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

What is going on and how can I fix this?

**Update:** This seems to be only happening in Chrome. Why?

Comment: possibly related: [Percentage Heights in Flexbox: Chrome/Safari vs Firefox/IE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

The `layout-column` has `max-height: 100%` not `height`. So you need set the `height` of this(I don't know why it works without content).

You can fix this by insert `height` for this `div`. Try this:

```
<div flex="50" layout="column" style="height: 100%">
```

Hope this help.