# Flexbox row inside flexbox column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a layout like this:

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and css for it:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.flexbox .main {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.flexbox .header,
.flexbox .footer {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

in the above `.main` column is stretched 100% `height`, all this works perfect, now adding `.flexbox-row` inside `.main`:

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="flexbox-row">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second"></div>
      <div class="third"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and css:

```css
.flexbox-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.flexbox-row .first,
.flexbox-row .second,
.flexbox-row .third {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.flexbox-row .second {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

but for some reason `.main` column the second one does not stretch 100% in `height` anymore.

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qiyobagepa/edit?html,css,js,output) demo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `height:100%` to `.flexbox-row`

I've simplified your rules, there were unnecessary properties there.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.flexbox .main {
  flex: 1;
  background: red
}
.flexbox .header,
.flexbox .footer {
  background: green;
  padding:1em
}
.flexbox-row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
.flexbox-row .first,
.flexbox-row .second,
.flexbox-row .third {
  background: #C9E1F4;
  padding: 1em;
}
.flexbox-row .second {
  flex: 1;
  background: #A8EDAC
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="flexbox-row">
      <div class="first">First</div>
      <div class="second">Main</div>
      <div class="third">Third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

> In Chrome and Safari, the height of (non flex) children are not
>   recognized in percentages. However Firefox and IE recognize and scale
>   the children based on percentage heights.

[Source](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

So a workaround for that is adding `.position:relative` to `.main` and `position:absolute`, `width`/`height:100%` to `.flexbox-row`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
.flexbox .main {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  position: relative
}
.flexbox .header,
.flexbox .footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 1em
}
.flexbox-row {
  display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
.flexbox-row .first,
.flexbox-row .second,
.flexbox-row .third {
  background: #C9E1F4;
  padding: 1em;
}
.flexbox-row .second {
  flex: 1;
  background: #A8EDAC
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="flexbox-row">
      <div class="first">First</div>
      <div class="second">Main</div>
      <div class="third">Third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, height of flexbox-row was the problem. So simple.

Comment: I just tested it in chrome, and does not work right, FF and Edge is ok. Maybe webkit needs additional properties.

Comment: @Alko it is a known Issue -  *In Chrome and Safari, the height of (non flex) children are not recognized in percentages. However Firefox and IE recognize and scale the children based on percentage heights. [Chrome bug](http://crbug.com/341310)* - so you might use `vh`

Comment: possibly related: [Percentage Heights in Flexbox: Chrome/Safari vs Firefox/IE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276)

Comment: Thanks I did not know that. I might have to find another workaround. I have  accepted your answer.

Comment: @Alko solution would be to add `position: relative;` to `.main`, and `position: absolute;width: 100%;height:100%;` to `.flexbox-row`